# Data Profiling using Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, data-analysis, aws-glue, data-profiling

I'm trying create a PySpark function that can take input as a Dataframe and returns a data-profile report. I already used describe and summary function which gives out result like min, max, count etc. but I need a detailed report like unique_values and have some visuals too.

If anyone knows anything that can help, feel free to comment below.

A dynamic function that can give the desired output as mentioned above will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1:

If the spark dataframe is not to big you can try using a pandas  profiling library like `sweetviz`, e.g.:

```py
import sweetviz as sv

my_report = sv.analyze(source=(data.toPandas(), "EDA Report"))
my_report.show_notebook() # to show in a notebook cell
my_report.show_html(filepath="report.html") # Will generate the report into a html file
```

It looks like:

[image]

You can check more features about sweetviz [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/powerful-eda-exploratory-data-analysis-in-just-two-lines-of-code-using-sweetviz-6c943d32f34) like how to compare populations.

Option 2:

Use a profiler that admits `pyspark.sql.DataFrame`, e.g. `ydata-profiling`.

Answer (score 1):

[ydata-profiling](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling) currently support Spark dataframes, so it should be the most adequate choice:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark profiling example") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("{insert-csv-file-path}")
df.printSchema()

report = ProfileReport(df, title=”Profiling pyspark DataFrame”)
report.to_file('profile.html')
```

An example report looks like this: https://ydata-profiling.ydata.ai/examples/master/census/census_report.html